# Reset file field through stimulus controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, hotwire

I have a form which is submitted through stimulus controller.

#form.html.haml

```
= form_with url: my_url, multipart: true, data: { turbo_frame: 'document_table_content', turbo_action: 'advanced' } do |f|
  = f.file_field 'documents[files]', multiple: true, direct_upload: true, data: { 'dropzone-target' => 'input' }
```

#dropzone_controller.js

```
Rails.fire(this.form, "submit");
```

This works, I want additionally after submit to reset the file_field, I have the target through `this.inputTarget` but I don't know how to remove all files from this form field.

Answer (score 0):

It has always seemed strange to me, but to achieve the reset of the file input you have to reset the form!

```js
document.querySelector('form').reset()
```